# Is this correct? 'Dear Reddit, today, I messed up.'

Tags: punctuation

So there is a subforum on Reddit that I have recently come across, and in the header it has the following text:

> Dear Reddit, today, I messed up.

The issue that I see with this is that the comma after the word 'today' does not appear to be correctly placed.

This came up in a recent conversation with a friend of mine, in which I stated that the comma is incorrectly placed and instead it should be written like the following:

> Dear Reddit, today I messed up.

However, he argues that the comma is correctly placed and does not need to be corrected.
Would anyone be able to provide some information about this?

Thank you!

Comment: Ah, a newcomer to TIFU, eh?

Comment: Haha, yes! @socrates

Comment: Either one is fine. If you think of a comma as a pause, the first version just puts more emphasis on the word 'today'. I don't think it requires the emphasis though and it because of the 'dear' it doesn't look as nice as without the comma. I'd personally choose the latter.

Comment: I would see this as a comma splice; a semicolon or colon I think would work better.

Comment: @Michael ; a comma is not, and cannot be thought of as, a pause. There are specific rules of where and when to use a comma, and whether a sentence requires an emphasis is not part of these rules - nor is whether you think the comma looks "nice" or not in a sentence or what you would personally choose. Please bear that in mind.

Comment: @Max I would refute you myself but [the entire first paragraph of this](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/punctuation/mastering-the-art-of-comma-usage/commas-pauses-shifts-and-contrasted-coordinate-elements/) does it quite succinctly.

Comment: @Michael ; Sorry to disappoint you, but, unfortunately, it's either that you interpreted that paragraph wrong or that that paragraph is entirely wrong itself. I think it's trying to say that in some cases, where there is a choice of whether to put a comma or not, it is a matter of emphasis of whether you actually decide to place it. But that is a simple way of looking at it - not an actual rule.

Comment: @Max I find it amusing that you've added superfluous commas for emphasis. Nice one, chum.

Comment: @Michael , would you mind telling me where?

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is right - the comma is correctly placed. 'Today' is an introductory prepositional phrase, meaning it should be set off with a comma.

The comma after "Reddit", interestingly, is also right, though doesn't sound so: "Dear Reddit" is an addressed subject, and addressed subjects should always be set off with a comma and nothing else.